# Is there a Bitcoin exchange comparison site (fees, details) like distrowatch.com or http://cmsmatrix.org/?

Tags: exchanges, websites, exchange-fees

Is there anybody that knows of a site that does a fairly thorough comparison of all currently active exchanges, and their fees especially. Like there is distrowatch.com and cmsmatrix.org.

The closest i've seen is on the bitcoin wiki : https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins (and related pages)

anyone?

Comment: Would be a lot of work to build and maintain.  

If the exchanges would show their fees (trading fee, cost of deposits, withdrawals, conversions, etc.) in a clear manner and communicate changes (rather than in-place ninja edits) it would be easier to manually collect this info.  Even the largest exchange is inconsistent -- one day announcements are on Facebook.  The next with a press release.  Then another on the forum.  Then on the support site.  And that is just one exchange! Sometimes these changes are bad news for the consumer (e.g., rise in fee) so they aren't well communicated either.

Answer (score 3):

Try Exchange war:

https://exchangewar.info/

which shows even the most popular pairs for each exchange.

Answer (score 2):

[bitcoincharts.com](http://www.bitcoincharts.com/) pretty much is what you look for I think. They got a huge list of exchanges and detailed informations about each site.

Comment: They just show market info (high, low, bid, ask etc.), don't they? I don't see their fees in there anywhere, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I agree; this is not a complete comparison of exchanges (the question mentions fees especially!) but only of their bids/asks.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new [Bitcoin exchange comparison chart](https://99bitcoins.com/best-2015-bitcoin-exchanges-bitcoin-exchange-comparison-review/) on 99Bitcoins.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bitcointalk thread where a member posted important statistics and reviews about some of the primary exchanges. This thread compares the following exchanges:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=695082.0

Bitstamp

BTC-e

Bitfinex

BTCchina

HUOBI

LakeBTC

Kraken

CAVirtex

OKCoin

LocalBitcoins

ANX

hitbtc

CoinMKT

[Bleutrade](https://bleutrade.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can see a full list of Bitcoin exchanges at http://bitcoinx.io/exchanges, although I don't see a comparison component per say; but there is a rankings list of top Bitcoin exchanges to see which one is better.