# Which exchange is better for average users?

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins

How do bitstamp, btc-e, bitfinex, lakebtc, btcchina, compare on **trading fee**, **deposit way**, and **withdrawal speed**?

Which is the most comfortable for us?

Comment: This type of question is offtopic here, but checkout [http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/is-there-a-bitcoin-exchange-comparison-site-fees-details-like-distrowatch-com](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4376/5406).